# Python newbie: What does this code do?

Tags: python

This is a snippet from Google AppEngine tutorial.

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

I'm not quite sure what **`debug=True`** does inside the constructor call. 
Does it create a local variable with name `debug`, assign `True` to it, and pass it to constructor, or is this a way to set a class instance member variable's value in constructor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python functions accept keyword arguments. If you define a function like so:

```
def my_func(a, b='abc', c='def'):
    print a, b, c
```

You can call it like this:

```
my_func('hello', c='world')
```

And the result will be:

```
hello abc world
```

You can also support dynamic keyword arguments, using special syntax:

```
def my_other_func(a, *b, **c):
    print a, b, c
```

- `*b` means that the `b` variable will take all non-named arguments after `a`, as a `tuple` object.
- `**c` means that the `c` variable will take all named arguments, as a `dict` object.

If you call the function like this:

```
my_other_func('hello', 'world', 'what a', state='fine', what='day')
```

You will get:

```
hello ('world', 'what a') {'state': 'fine', 'what': 'day'}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!!! This is apparently a better way of overriding a default argument value than how c/c++ does, where I will have to also pass b='abc' in your example.

Comment: Indeed, that is one of the uses of named arguments =)

Comment: Compare/Take a look also at Ada language: also Ada had named arguments

Answer (score 4):

Neither -- rather, `webapp.WSGIApplication` takes an optional argument named `debug`, and this code is passing the value `True` for that parameter.

The reference page for `WSGIApplication` is [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/wsgiapplicationclass.html) and it clearly shows the optional `debug` argument and the fact that it defaults to `False` unless explicitly passed in.

As the page further makes clear, passing `debug` as `True` means that helpful debugging information is shown to the browser if and when an exception occurs while handling the request.

How exactly that effect is obtained (in particular, whether it implies the existence of an attribute on the instance of `WSGIApplication`, or how that hypothetical attribute might be named) is an internal, undocumented implementation detail, which we're not supposed to worry about (of course, you can study the sources of `WSGIApplication` in the SDK if you *do* worry, or just want to learn more about one possible implementation of these specs!-).

Answer (score 3):

It's using named arguments.  See [Using Optional and Named Arguments](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/optional_arguments.html).